# Nested Query With Latest Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a SQL Server 2008 database. I need to get a specific order for a customer and their latest order ID and latest order data. My challenge here is, I need the data in a single row. Currently, I'm trying the following query:

```
 SELECT
  o.*,
  c.[FirstName],
  c.[LastName],
  c.[PlayerName],
  (SELECT TOP 1 o2.CreatedDate, o2.ID  FROM [Order] o2 ORDER BY [CreatedOn] DESC)
 FROM
  [Order] o,
  [Customer] c
 WHERE  
  o.[ID]=c.[CustomerID]
```

When I execute this query, I get the following error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

As you can imagine, there are scenarios where a customer will NOT have a previous order. How do I do this and get the result into a single row?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `o.[ID]=c.[CustomerID]`?

Comment: Are you looking for the latest `ID` or the latest `CreatedON` date? which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different way to do it using a CTE.

```
WITH LatestOrder AS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Order] ORDER BY [CreatedOn] DESC) 
 SELECT
  o.*,
  c.[FirstName],
  c.[LastName],
  c.[PlayerName],
  lo.CreatedDate,
  lo.ID
 FROM [Order] o
 JOIN [Customer] c
    ON o.[ID]=c.[CustomerID]
 CROSS JOIN LatestOrder lo
```

Comment: +1 for using `CTE` to cross join. This is much efficient I guess. Also I think `o.[ID]=c.[CustomerID]` is a mistake which is not your fault anyway....

Comment: Never know.  I've seen systems where ID = CustomerID so I don't judge :).  Personally I also like the FROM TableA JOIN TableB syntax MUCH better than the FROM TableA, TableB syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT
  o.*,
  c.[FirstName],
  c.[LastName],
  c.[PlayerName],
  (SELECT TOP 1 o2.CreatedDate FROM [Order] o2 ORDER BY [CreatedOn] DESC),
  (SELECT TOP 1 o2.ID FROM [Order] o2 ORDER BY [CreatedOn] DESC)
 FROM
  [Order] o,
  [Customer] c
 WHERE  
  o.[ID]=c.[CustomerID]
```

The error is saying you cant select two fields in your sub query.  So you have to do them separately.

Comment: Joining tables with where clause is not recommended. Better to use `Join`

Comment: @Kaf Yes I agree but I was merely correctly the syntax error in his query